# How to query from one SQL DB and insert into another SQL DB table on same server?

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have the following databases on the same server:

```
[DB1].[TableA] with columns [zipcode] and [city]
[DB2].[TableB] with columns [zipcode] and [city]
```

How can I query (for example, 5 largest zip codes) from `DB1.TableA` and insert those rows into `DB1.TableB`?

***RESOLVED UPDATE***

I discovered why I wasn't getting my queries working. I am using a SQL Azure Database and cross DB querying is NOT supported. Have to query the data into my C# logic and then take that data and put it into the other database table.

Comment: What do you mean by "largest"?  Most number of entries per zip code?  Which RDBMS?

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. And honestly, selecting data from one table and inserting it into another table, regardless of whether the second table is on the same connection as the first is a non-issue.

Comment: Largest meaning highest value? example: 23345<90210 

This is what I have tried: 

INSERT INTO [DB2].[TableB] (Zipcode)
SELECT Location FROM [DB1].[TableA] 
WHERE Location > 5000

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [DB2].[TableB] (ZipCode)
  SElECT TOP 5 ZipCode FROM [DB1].[TableA] ORDER BY ZipCode desc
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but discovered why it wasn't working because I had something similar to what you suggested. I am using a SQL Azure Database and cross DB querying is NOT supported.